# Update column based on duplication

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates, sql-update

I need to update the records in table based on the duplication.

Here's the table structure:

```
SHIPMENT  VALUE  GROUP_ID
A100       23
A100       25
A200       29
```

I need to assign group_id in a way that the one all shipments will be updated with GROUP_ID 10.
The shipment that has more than one instance, the second instance will be updated to GROUP_ID 12.

```
SHIPMENT  VALUE  GROUP_ID
A100       23      10
A100       25      12
A200       29      10
```

can it be done in one update?

Comment: _Second instance_ -  according to what?

Comment: You shouldn't store such values. If someone inserts/deletes duplicates, you will probably end up with inconsistent data. Create a view instead. (Or at least use triggers to manage the column.)

Comment: according to SHIPMENT column.  Its just a one-time activity for data migration

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Done. edited with the DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one `update` option; it checks whether `value` is equal to minimum `value` per each `shipment`. If so, set it to `10`; otherwise, set it to `12`. See if it helps.

```
SQL> select * from test order by shipment, value;

SHIP      VALUE   GROUP_ID
---- ---------- ----------
A100         23
A100         25
A200         29

SQL> update test t set
  2    t.group_id = (select case when t.value = x.min_value then 10
  3                              else 12
  4                         end
  5                  from (select a.shipment,
  6                               min(a.value) min_value
  7                        from test a
  8                        group by a.shipment
  9                       ) x
 10                  where x.shipment = t.shipment
 11                 );

3 rows updated.

SQL> select * from test order by shipment, value;

SHIP      VALUE   GROUP_ID
---- ---------- ----------
A100         23         10
A100         25         12
A200         29         10

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want `case` and `row_number()`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by shipment order by value) = 1
             then 10 else 12
        end) as groupid
from t;
```

Comment: That's exactly what I need.  How to use it in UPDATE query? i'm failing to do so.